# Rust: Asynchronous transaction callbacks

Tags: rust, async-await, callback

I have (synchronous) Rust code which handles database transactions, simplified:

```
struct Context<'a> {
    x: &'a str, // Would be e.g. pooled connection in real code
}

impl<'a> Context<'a> {
    pub fn read_value(&mut self) -> String {
        self.x.to_string()
    }
}

fn run_transaction(f: impl FnOnce(&mut Context) -> String) -> String {
    let mut ctx = Context { x: "test" };
    f(&mut ctx)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{} (1)", run_transaction(|ctx| ctx.read_value()));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eca967af9f17652882af909f094a9c43)

I now want to make this code asynchronous:

```
struct AsyncContext<'a> {
    x: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> AsyncContext<'a> {
    pub async fn read_value(&mut self) -> String {
        self.x.to_string()
    }
}

async fn run_async_transaction<F>(f: impl FnOnce(&mut AsyncContext) -> F) -> String
    where F: std::future::Future<Output = String>
{
    let mut ctx = AsyncContext { x: "test" };
    f(&mut ctx).await
}

fn main() {
    futures::executor::block_on(async move {
        println!("{} (2)", run_async_transaction(|ctx| ctx.read_value()).await)
    });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=70354347635eb9b36bd72a49a06d5113)

This, however, fails with:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:20:60
   |
20 |         println!("{} (2)", run_async_transaction(|ctx| ctx.read_value()).await)
   |                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #3 defined on the body at 20:50...
  --> src/main.rs:20:50
   |
20 |         println!("{} (2)", run_async_transaction(|ctx| ctx.read_value()).await)
   |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that the type `AsyncContext<'_>` is not borrowed for too long
  --> src/main.rs:20:56
   |
20 |         println!("{} (2)", run_async_transaction(|ctx| ctx.read_value()).await)
   |                                                        ^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the call at 20:28...
  --> src/main.rs:20:28
   |
20 |         println!("{} (2)", run_async_transaction(|ctx| ctx.read_value()).await)
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so type `impl core::future::future::Future` of expression is valid during the expression
  --> src/main.rs:20:28
   |
20 |         println!("{} (2)", run_async_transaction(|ctx| ctx.read_value()).await)
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What do I have to change to make it work, similar to the synchronous version?

Comment: The trouble is with your executor implementation, there are so many issues with it in maintaining context that it's difficult to outline, and there is a full blown tutorial for this on how to do it here: https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/02_execution/04_executor.html

Comment: @AhmedMasud I'm using the standard `futures::executor::block_on` executor (just for demonstration). I doubt there are many issues with it